# Is there a way to programmatically change the collection of a gallery in wix

Tags: javascript, database, collections, velo

Is there a way to programmatically change the collection of a gallery in wix. I have a wix store and I want to add costume filter options. I know you can add some in the editor but if the collection is empty I cant add it to the filter options and I don't want to have to go through the editor and add that filter every time I get an inventory of that product. So I want to use radio buttons and write my own filter code and if the collection is empty I want to display that or show some type of message. I have the coded filter successfully running a query to find all products that contain a certain "String". I want to take that array of products and populate a store-gridGallery programmatically but I don't see any properties of the gridGallery that allow me to do this. Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the store grid gallery with a repeater, creating your own store product gallery. Then, using Wix Code inputs and `wix-data` `filter`, you can code your own set of filters.

e.g.

Assume you are using a dataset connected to a repeater to show the store products as a gallery. You can then set the dataset filter using

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

export function filterElement_onChange(event) {
  let value = $w('#filterElement').value;
  $w('#dataset1').setFilter(wixData.filter().eq('a field', value));
}
```